# Keep pom.xml generated from eclipse after WAR export

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, export, pom.xml

As the title says.
I am exporting a dynamic web project from eclipse to WAR file.
I imagine this: Eclipse generates a POM file according to project properties. WAR is packaged using default eclipse Maven plugin. 
What I want is to keep the POM after the WAR file packaging so that the WAR file can be generated through Maven console commands afterwards without the need to import the project in eclipse.
I've read suggestions that the original code can be copied into a new Maven project in eclipse, but I can't seem to grasp the idea: I check the "Create a simple project (skip archetype selection)" and java/resources are created. Where does the WebContent folder go?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your first created an eclipse project und now you want eclipse to be aware that you have a maven-project.

First you need a maven eclipse plugin (m2e): got to eclipse marketplace and search for "maven". There will be a Maven Integration for Eclipse Plugin (m2e). Install it.

Than right click on your project choose "Configure" -> "Convert to Maven Project".

Or you can do this from commandline with: mvn eclipse:eclipse And than import in eclipse as "Import" -> "Exsting Project in Eclipse".